# Passing ID from View to Controller in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

May be it's a duplicate question and a long question. But I didn't get my solution and problem is easy to expert.

In my `HomeController` there are three ActionResult() named `Index()`, `Customer()` and `Item()`.

> Model Class:

```
namespace Customer.Models
{
    public class CustomerInfo
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am talking about my `Customer()`. In `Customer()` a list will be return to `CustomerView` page.

> HomeController:

```
List<CustomerInfo> customers = new List<CustomerInfo>();
public ActionResult Customer()
 {
       customers.Add(new CustomerInfo { CustomerName= "Nafeeur"});
       customers.Add(new CustomerInfo { CustomerName = "Rasel" });
       customers.Add(new CustomerInfo { CustomerName = "Fagun" });
       return View(customers);
 }
```

`CustomerView` page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer.Models.CustomerInfo>
@using Customer.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<h1>Customer Name</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach(CustomerInfo customer in @Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(customer.CustomerName, "Index", "Customer", new {id = customer.CustomerId})
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

From this View page I'm passing id to another Controller page named `CustomerController`

Code:

```
namespace Customer.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var list = new List<CustomerInfo>();
            var item = list.Find(x => x.GetId(id));
            return View(item);
        }
    }
}
```

View page of `CustomerController` View:

```
@model Customer.Models.CustomerInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customer Index</h2>


<h3>@Model.CustomerId</h3>
<h3>@Model.CustomerName</h3>
<h3>@Model.ItemName</h3>
```

My problem is, when I click on any customer it is not working.

Error:
[image]

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Your not setting any values for `CustomerId` - they will all be `0` (the default for `int`) so the value of `id` in the `Index()` method will be `0`

Comment: And in that method, you just generating a new list that does not contain any items so there will be no items to return

Comment: *"My problem is, when I click on any customer it is not working."* isn't really a question... What isn't working? What have you tried to fix the issue? Are you getting errors? People are here to help, granted - but in some instances we don't want to have to copy/paste your entire code to compile it and debug it ourselves. You will need to perform some debugging beforehand, and try and describe the *exact* problem you're having, if possible.

Comment: I want the description of Every customer details. But when I click to the customer it is going to home page. Errors are added by image.

Comment: You should have a db context instance to retrieve the customer details. Then use DbSet Find to get customer details.

Comment: I didn't use database. Why I need db context? @ShawnYan

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me (at least the reason you are getting the error) is that you just need to implement GetId() within you CustomerInfo class. Unless I'm totally off (and I might be) this is not some kind of implicit method that you can just use. You have to write it. For example *something* like this could go into your CustomerInfo class.

```
public int GetId()
{
   return this.CustomerId;
}
```

However, like Stephen pointed out in a comment, you still have to actually set the id for the customer. If you aren't using a database (as it appears you are not from your comment) and you are just creating some kind of a demo app, you need to just write some kind of method in your code that sets the id for each of those customers in your list (i.e. Nafeer, Rasel, Fagun).

Hope this helps.